# PHPStorm Built in Terminal - How do I backspace words?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, phpstorm

I love PHPStorm's built in terminal, all my zsh aliases work properly and it's super convenient.

The only thing it's missing is the ability to backspace by words (like I can in OSX's default terminal, with the `option` + `backspace` keys).

Is there any way to get that functionality in PHPStorm's built in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

By default the *zle* (zsh command line editor) command to backspace whole words - `backward-kill-word` (or `vi-backward-kill-word` if you are using *viins* keymap) - is also bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Should this not be the case for you, you can set this with

```
bindkey '^W' backward-kill-word
```

in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't currently possible. Please vote for [IDEA-113214](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113214)